# jQuery Animate image twiching

Tags: jquery, image, resize, jquery-animate

I have a problem with animating an image with JS. When I only animate `width` and `height` it works fine. Problem occurs when I add `top/marginTop`, or `left/marginLeft` to it. The reason I want to use it, is the zoom effect. However I think it is firstly adding `width` and `height`, than it adds `top/left` values. It produces "twitching" effect which looks bad and I can't get rid of it.

here is working example of my simple slider http://łuckoś.pl/slider/

I tried everything, even the `jQuery.fx.interval = 50;`

thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better result, you must use CSS properties like that:

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:489px;
    height:178px;
    position:relative;

}
#container img{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 4s ease-out;
    transition: all 4s ease-out;
}

#container img.zoom { 
   -moz-transform: scale(2);
   -webkit-transform: scale(2);
   -o-transform: scale(2);
   transform: scale(2);
   -ms-transform: scale(2);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',
   M11=2, M12=-0, M21=0, M22=2);
}
```

and javascript :

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('img').addClass('zoom');
});
```

When you add zoom class, the image is scaled to 2 in 4 secondes.

See the complete demonstrate : http://jsfiddle.net/rNY6T/18/

Comment: This is not what I needed but thank you, I finally got the additional part to move the zooming place it was `translate(5em,0);`  this way I can move the zoom randomly :) thanks, for the jsfiddle and your time!

Comment: I have a question. This kind of animation won't work in IE ( testing IE 8 currently ). However `http://codecanyon.net/item/estro-jquery-ken-burns-slider-wordpress-plugin/full_screen_preview/356713` works, this is the effect I desire. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to animate the width proportionally with the left position and height with the top position. As you reduce the width of 2px, you stagger from 1px to the left.

Comment: I added the values by valid counted ratio of the image, even when adding 100 width moving it 50 to left ( so it should stay in place and zoom vertically ) it is "twitching"

Answer (score 0):

When you need to zoom.. add this..

```
-moz-transform: scale(2); 
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
```

I think the IE equivalent is `-ms-transform` but I haven't used it with `scale`.

Comment: this is nice, thank you, but I still wan't to be able to move the zoomed image to top/left. In my `animate` function, to randomly move the zooming image. With `top/left` it is "Twiching" agian